# Convolution of $L^1(G)$ functions with elements of $M(G)$.

Tags: harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a non-discrete locally compact group with left Haar measure $\mu$.

There is an isometric embedding of $L^{1}(G)\to M(G), f\mapsto fd\mu$.

Since $G$ is not discrete, the point-mass measure $\delta_{x}$ is not in $M_{a}(G)$, but it is still a non-zero element of $M(G)$, and so can be convoluted with elements of $L^{1}(G)$.

Taking $(e_{\alpha})$ to be an approximate identity for $L^{1}(G)$.

Does $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{\alpha}\delta_{x}*e_{\alpha}$ exist in $M(G)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By $\widehat{\ast}$ I'll denote convilotion in $M(G)$. Each $f\in L_1(G)$ we may regard as measure $fd\mu\in M_a(G)$ and in this case we have 
$$
\nu\;\widehat{\ast}\;fd\mu=\nu\ast f
$$
for each $\nu\in M(G)$.

Now recall that $\lim_\alpha e_\alpha d\mu=\delta_e$ in $M(G)$ strongly, so 
$$
\lim_\alpha\delta_x\ast e_\alpha
=\lim_\alpha\delta_x \;\widehat{\ast}\; e_\alpha d\mu
=\delta_x \;\widehat{\ast}\;\lim_\alpha e_\alpha d\mu
=\delta_x \;\widehat{\ast}\;\delta_e
=\delta_{xe}
=\delta_x
$$

Comment: Thanks Norbert.  Can you refer me to where I might find the proof that $e_{\alpha}\to \delta_{e}$?

Comment: I think it is easy to do by hand. If you want a reference you can find this in section 3.3 in Banach algebras and automatic continuity. H. Garth Dales

Comment: @Norbert I have a doubt regarding Fourier algebras. I guess you could help.

Comment: @Mambo it would be better if you ask your question via standard tools of the site. Do not use comments for this purpose.

Comment: @Norbert I have posted a question regarding this. I don't know how to invite you there

Comment: My poor intuition says $A(G)$ separates compact sets but I don't know the proof. I'm not a specialist on this subject.